# Please help me get a grip on UIGestureRecognizers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am having the hardest time figuring out gesture recognizers and such on iOS.  Unfortunately a lot of the documentation by apple appears to be in Objective-C and/or it doesn't give you examples that show what values can go in. Could you show me some examples of how to the the following things.

1. Get the current position of each touch event on the screen. If the finger isn't down then return false.
2. Make a direction recognizer other then the 4 main directions. Currently my code looks like this

```
var leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("HandleSwipes:"))
leftSwipe.direction = .Left
view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
```

However what if I wanted to detect diagonal movement? Their isn't a `.Diagonal`.  So the detection of a gesture works in the direction (0.5, 0.5).

3. Going back to the code I put before I have a function that I check the direction in

```
func HandleSwipes(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.direction == .Left) {
        Label.text = "Left"
    }
}
```

What if I want this swipe to only work for the 2nd finger down?  Also how would I get the ending, and starting position of that gesture? (preferably inside of that function)

4. How can I find out how long it has taken the finger to do the gesture (getting from point A to point B).

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with swift, but in objective-c, this is how you will obtain the current position of a touch event.

```
CGPoint _originalCenter;

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {   
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
         // if the gesture has just started, record the current centre location
        _originalCenter = self.center;
    }
```

Hope this helps answer the first part of your question.